# Wordpress - Renaming URLs on the fly

Tags: wordpress

Im wondering if someone could give me a bit of advice.

Im looking for a plugin that allows me to rename URL's of posts and pages on the actual page itself, so they can go from:

http://www.example.com/post-here/

to something like

http://www.example.com/my-name/my-lastname/post-here

if that makes sense, i want to be able to name these URL's anything i want from within the post/page page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the admin, inside options click on permalink.

Then you're able to set URL'S, to make something like  your example this try :

/%author%/%postname%/

You can read the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) to see all options

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean but why don't use the redirection plug-in?